# How to update an article with images using summernote in core php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.

I'm working on a blog website and I've successfully added blog posts to the database now I am going to update that.
I am using summernote editor to add post content with images. I am having trouble to display content in summernote editor textarea field.

**My HTML**

i can see the value of meta title

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label" for="val-username">Meta Title <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="val-username" name="meta_title" value="<?php
     echo $row['meta_title']; ?>">
</div>
```

I can't see my description in the textarea field (I have option in database and can see content when I use  not )

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-form-label" for="val-username">Post Content <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <textarea name="description" class="summernote form-control" cols="30" rows="10">
     <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

i have also used this method to display content but it also not works

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-form-label" for="val-username">Post Content <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <textarea name="description" class="summernote form-control" cols="30" rows="10">
        <?php echo isset($row['description']) ? htmlspecialchars_decode($row['description']) : ''; ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I am seeing this error

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\blogweb\admin\update-post.php on line 150

Please help me to figure out the problem and solve this issue.
I'm waiting for your response.